# MassTransit/Quartz.NET schedule works for InMemory but not in persistent mode

Tags: masstransit, quartz.net

When using InMemoryMessageScheduler with Quartz, the ScheduledMessage actually gets scheduled and the "Message" is published at the defined time.
The problem is when the Quartz with persisting option is used, the message is persisted into the database, the ScheduledMessage is consumed by the ScheduleMessageConsumer BUT the "Message" is never published at the defined time.

I've used [Sample-GettingStarted](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-GettingStarted) and I've added the next changes:

QuartzConfig:

```
public class QuartzConfig : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public QuartzConfig(string connectionString)
    {
        this["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "MassTransit-Scheduler";
        this["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "AUTO";
        this["quartz.serializer.type"] = "json";
        this["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
        this["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz";

        this["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
        this["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "myDS";
        this["quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider"] = "Npgsql";
        this["quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString"] = connectionString;
        this["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
    }

    public NameValueCollection ToNameValueCollection()
    {
        return this.Aggregate(new NameValueCollection(), (seed, current) =>
        {
            seed.Add(current.Key, current.Value);
            return seed;
        });
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.AddConsumer<MessageConsumer>();
                    var scheduler = CreateScheduler();

                    x.UsingRabbitMq((context,cfg) =>
                    {
                        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("quartz", endpoint =>
                        {
                            endpoint.Consumer(() => new ScheduleMessageConsumer(scheduler));
                            endpoint.Consumer(() => new CancelScheduledMessageConsumer(scheduler));
                            cfg.UseMessageScheduler(endpoint.InputAddress);
                        });
                        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                    });
                });
                services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });

    static IScheduler CreateScheduler()
    {
        var dbConnectionString = "Host=localhost;Database=scheduler;Port=5432;Password=pass;User ID=user;Pooling=true;MaxPoolSize=200;Enlist=true";
        var quartzConfig = new QuartzConfig(dbConnectionString)
            .ToNameValueCollection();

        ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(quartzConfig);
        return schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

Worker.cs:

```
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    readonly IBus _bus;

    public Worker(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await _bus.CreateMessageScheduler().SchedulePublish(DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), new Message { Text = $"I really hope this is scheduled {DateTime.Now}" });
            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess this is happening because there the hosted service for the scheduler is not added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quartz Integration package connects a bus observer to handle the start/stop of Quartz.NET, as [shown in the source](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/2b34054a18dd92da9d7508f7aa67e06256311030/src/Scheduling/MassTransit.QuartzIntegration/QuartzIntegrationExtensions.cs#L105). Unfortunately the documentation isn't great on how to do it.